# How can I update a component's state based on its current state with React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my component, I'm running a function that iterates through keys in state and updates properties as async functions complete. However, it looks like it's updating the state to the state as it existed prior to the function running.

This is the code for my component:

```
interface VideoDownloaderProps {
  videos: string[];
}
const VideoDownloader: React.FC<VideoDownloaderProps> = ({ videos }) => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState({} as { [key: string]: string });
  const [isDownloading, setIsDownloading] = useState(false);

  async function initialSetup(vids: string[]) {
    const existingKeys = await keys();
    setProgress(
      vids.reduce<{ [key: string]: string }>((a, b) => {
        a[b] = existingKeys.indexOf(b) > -1 ? "downloaded" : "queued";
        return a;
      }, {})
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    initialSetup(videos);
  }, [videos]);

  async function download() {
    setIsDownloading(true);
    const existingKeys = await keys();
    for (const videoUrl of videos) {
      if (existingKeys.indexOf(videoUrl) === -1) {
        setProgress({ ...progress, [videoUrl]: "downloading" });
        const response = await fetch(videoUrl);
        const videoBlob = await response.blob();
        await set(videoUrl, videoBlob);
      }
      setProgress({ ...progress, [videoUrl]: "downloaded" });
    }
    setIsDownloading(false);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={isDownloading} onClick={download}>
        Download Videos
      </button>
      {Object.keys(progress).map(url => (
        <p key={url}>{`${url} - ${progress[url]}`}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Essentially, this iterates through a list of URLs, downloads them, and then sets the URL in state to `"downloaded"`. However, the behavior I'm seeing is that the URL shifts from `"queued"` to `"downloading"` and then back to `"queued"` once the next URL begins downloading.

I think the culprit is this line:

```
setProgress({ ...progress, [videoUrl]: "downloaded" });
```

I think `progress` is always in the same state it was when `download` executes.

Prior to Hooks, I could pass an updater function to `setState`, but I'm not sure how to reuse existing state in a `useState` hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an updater function just like with `setState`. So, in this code, you'd run:

```
setProgress(progress => ({ ...progress, [videoUrl]: "downloading" }));
```

This will pass the current value of `progress` allowing you to update the state based on its current value.